# How do I get Initial Jobless Claims and Continued Jobless Claims data?

Tags: api, labor

I'm having a difficult time going through the API trying to find out how I can get Initial Jobless Claims and Continued Jobless Claims data. The documentation isn't very clear - or I'm not looking in the right areas.

Comment: Are you referring to the US Weekly UI Claims as shown [here](https://www.dol.gov/ui/data.pdf)?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the API?

Comment: Please clarify by answering these questions and we will reopen. Thanks and welcome! :-)